# Decimal values getting scientific notation in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to load a csv file to sql server via python. The csv loading to sql is done by a different tool, and my problem is that the fields widths are not getting expanded letting the decimal values in my file get an scientific notation. I tried to save the file in xlsx format and expanded the field widths and when i imported using pandas, i could still see the decimal integers length getting truncated.

```
my excel( csv ) contains values of this format when expanded the col width
val             val 2
0.00000141     a
0.0000011      b
 
when not expanded
1.41E-6        a
1.1E-06        b
```

How can i load these to sql server without loosing the data?

```
The code i use for loading to sql is quite straightforward

df= pd.read_csv(read my file)
engine= sql.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://mydbname",fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql("mytablename", engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.8f' % x)  # Eight digits after the comma
```